# Dynamically Allocated Array of Pointers Keeps Rewriting Itself

Tags: c, string, pointers, structure

I'm trying to write a program to find the frequency of words in a file (words.txt) using a dynamically allocated array of pointers to store the words and
frequencies at which the words appear and print the results to another file (frequencies.txt).

Example:

Read from words.txt

```
apple
orange
apple
banana
orange
apple
```

Write to frequencies.txt:

```
3 apple
2 orange
1 banana
```

Here's the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct wordfreq 
{
  int count;
  char *word;
};

typedef struct wordfreq wordfreq;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wordfreq **wordarray;
    int size = 1, i, j, x, compare;
    char buffer[100];
    FILE *fp;

    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"!!!ERROR!!!\nNUMBER OF MISSING PARAMETERS: %d\n", 3-argc);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    wordarray = (wordfreq**)malloc(size*sizeof(wordfreq*));

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        wordarray[i] = (wordfreq *) malloc(sizeof(wordfreq*));
        wordarray[i]->word = "!";
        wordarray[i]->count = 0;
    }

    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",buffer) == 1)
    {
        printf("Word: %s\n", buffer);

        if(wordarray[0]->word == "!")
        {
            wordarray[0]->word = buffer;
            wordarray[0]->count = 1;
        }

        //Continued coding

        for(x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            printf("%d %s\n", wordarray[x]->count, wordarray[x]->word);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //wordarray = realloc(wordarray,size*sizeof(wordfreq*));

    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d %s\n", wordarray[i]->count, wordarray[i]->word);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    free(wordarray);

    return 0;
}
```

For now I'm simply trying to get the first value assigned (1 apple). The problem that I'm having is that when I try to assign the first value of the dynamic array, the value for wordarray->word changes with each read from the file, but it's supposed to stay as apple:

```
Word: apple
1 apple

Word: orange
1 orange

Word: apple
1 apple

Word: banana
1 banana

Word: orange
1 orange

Word: apple
1 apple

Results:
1 apple
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `wordarray[0]->word = buffer` - this isn't doing what you think it is. All this does is save the base address of `buffer` in the `word` member. There is only one `buffer`, and when finished everyone points to it. I suspect you need some dynamic allocation and `strcpy` or `strdup` if you don't mind stepping a little outside the standard library.

Comment: You were on the mark, strdup did it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `wordarray[0]->word = buffer` with `wordarray[0]->word = strdup(buffer)`

currently `wordarray[0]->word` is a pointer to `buffer` so every time you run the line `fscanf(fp,"%s",buffer)` you change it's value

** don't forget to free strdup memory at the end

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    free(wordarray[i]->word);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `free(wordarry);` do that?

Comment: no, it will just free the space you allocated for `wordarray`, not the space `strdup` allocated for each word

Comment: Okay thanks. Do I need to do that for `wordarray->count` as well or not because I'm not using `strdup` with it?

Comment: no need to, you should use `free` only on dynamically allocated variables

Answer (score 0):

Also, you don't know what `size` is. First, you can scan the file and find out size:

```
int size = 0;
while (!feof(fp))
{
    fscanf(fp, "%s\n", buffer);
    size++; //you have this many lines in the files
}
rewind(fp);
```

Comment: You're right about `size`, but I haven't gotten to handling multiple spaces for the array yet. I just wanted to get the problem of getting values into it covered and I plan on using `realloc()` to increase the size of the array as needed (it's what my professor wants).

Comment: @WoernerBro, yes my suggestion was sort of a cheat, it will need to read the file twice, and reading the file is a slow operation. You have to realloc or linked list or something.